# VBA - How to streamline the conversion from one time interval to another?

Tags: vba, performance, data-conversion

So I have 2 datasets, one with a time step of 1 minute, the other with a time step of fifteen minutes. I want to convert the 15min data set to the 1min data set by copying the values so that if 4:15 = x1 in the first set, 4:01 to 4:15 = X1 in the second data set.

I wrote the following code, which works fine. However, once past the first values the program slows down to a snail's pace, and takes multiple hours to complete the run.

So my question is: how can I improve the code I wrote so as to achieve completion quicker?

Example data:
[image: Data example]

```
Sub AddData()

Dim Query As Worksheet

Dim Time As String
Dim Time2 As String

Dim QueryRangeStart As Range
Dim QueryRangeFinish As Range
Dim QueryRange As Range
Dim Position As Range
Dim Position2 As Range


Set Query = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Not needed in example, I conserved it so as not to have to rewrite my code

For Each Position In Range(Range("start"), Range("start").End(xlDown)).Cells 'Start is the first cell containing a timestamp in the 15min dataset

Time = Position.Text
Time2 = Position.Offset(1, 0).Text
Set QueryRangeStart = Nothing
Set QueryRangeFinish = Nothing

    For Each Position2 In Range(Query.Range("A2"), Query.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Cells

        If InStr(1, Time, Position2.Text, 1) = 1 And QueryRangeStart Is Nothing Then
        Set QueryRangeStart = Range(Position2.Address(rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False, external:=True))
        End If

        If InStr(1, Time2, Position2.Text, 1) = 1 And QueryRangeFinish Is Nothing Then
        Test = False
        Set QueryRangeFinish = Range(Position2.Offset(-1, 0).Address(rowabsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False, external:=True))
        Exit For
        End If

    Next

    For Each Position2 In Range(QueryRangeStart, QueryRangeFinish).Cells

        Position2.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = Position.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: so you want the same values for each 15-minute interval, split up to 15 rows?  (or is the value ÷15 as well?)

Comment: You have a comment `'Not needed in example, I conserved it so as not to have to rewrite my code` yet the `Query` object **is** used in the example...?  I'm confused by the comment.

Comment: Also, its kind of a pain when questions have images of data or code.  **Which columns are all these fields in?**  Which columns are `Time` & `Time2` supposed to be looking at?

Comment: Originally I used the Query object because my data-sets were on different worksheets. However in the example I wanted to share, both sets were on the same sheet, so I didn't need an object to refer to another worksheet.

Comment: But you *are* referring to the `Query` object in this code, so even if the data's on the same worksheet, you still would have to declare it.

Comment: Yes, but I could erase all the references to it, and the code would still work.

Comment: I see what you're saying - i was confused since it's still best to have an object to refer to a specific sheet, even if there's only one sheet.  It can prevent various problems, such as confusion if there are multiple workbooks open.

Comment: To answer your first question, I want to have the same value for each 15-minute interval.

Comment: alright well you didn't answer the question about "which columns the data is in" which is probably why I couldn't run your code at all (getting "application defined error") so I was unclear on what it's doing so i slapped together a new procedure... but what is the end result?  Just a new list of two columns? - If so, how is the data in the first dataset relevant (besides the times)?

Comment: Time and Time2 look at the 15min dataset, Time being the starttime of the current value, and Time2 the starttime of the next value.

Comment: The end goal is to add a new column next to the existing data.

Comment: Are you looking at the existing 1-minute intervals because there 's a chance one could be missing?

Comment: I have a second solution too (slightly modified). posting now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble following your code since I wasn't sure which columns your data was in, so I built a new procedure:

```
Sub split15to1()

    Const colIn = 8   'column# where the input 15-mintue intervals are located (data next to it)
    Const colOut = 11 'column# where the output 1-minute intervals should go (data next to it)
    Const rwStart = 3 'row# where "everything" begins

    Dim rwIn As Long, rwOut As Long, x As Long
    rwIn = rwStart: rwOut = rwStart 'set start rows

    Do
        Debug.Print "Splitting: " & Cells(rwIn, colIn) & " : ";
        For x = 0 To 14
            Debug.Print x & ",";
            Cells(rwOut, colOut) = Cells(rwIn, colIn) + TimeSerial(0, x, 0) 'add [x]mins to input time
            Cells(rwOut, colOut + 1) = Cells(rwIn, colIn + 1) 'copy value from col next to input time
            rwOut = rwOut + 1 'next output row
        Next x
        Debug.Print "Done."
        rwIn = rwIn + 1 'next input row
    Loop Until Cells(rwIn, colIn) = "" 'is there data on the next row?

    MsgBox "Finished!"
End Sub
```

### Example output:

[image: img]

---

### Alternative

Slightly modified: No output time; place value next to existing data

```
Option Explicit

Sub split15to1()

    Const colIn = 8   'column# where the input 15-mintue intervals are located (data next to it)
    Const colOut = 4 'column# where the output 1-minute intervals should go (data next to it)
    Const rwStart = 3 'row# where "everything" begins

    Dim rwIn As Long, rwOut As Long, x As Long
    rwIn = rwStart: rwOut = rwStart 'set start rows

    Do
        Debug.Print "Splitting: " & Cells(rwIn, colIn) & " : ";
        For x = 0 To 14
            Debug.Print x & ",";
            Cells(rwOut, colOut) = Cells(rwIn, colIn + 1) 'put input data at output location
            rwOut = rwOut + 1 'next output row
        Next x
        Debug.Print "Done."
        rwIn = rwIn + 1 'next input row
    Loop Until Cells(rwIn, colIn) = "" 'is there data on the next row?

    MsgBox "Finished!"
End Sub
```

In case you're not aware the `Debug.Print` comments are for troubleshooting and print in the Immediate Window which you can open with CTRL+G from VBA.
If you're not using them, those lines can be deleted or ignored.

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm, and in a fraction of the time it took my program to work. I was overcomplexifing things.